# Creating application using phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I have created a website which works on a local server now I need to run it on every mobile device how I can proceed . I have heard that phone gap is used to make this possible..I have downloaded phone gapnow but dunno how to proceed on...please guide

Comment: check Phonegap Build Doc for more information.....http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.1.0/#googtrans(en)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must read all the documentation required before you are building an  you can read it from

```
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/index.html
```